# Square root of positive matrix operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $F_1,F_2$ be two complex Hilbert spaces.  Consider 
\begin{equation*}
T=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal{B}(F_1\oplus F_2).
\end{equation*}

> If $T$ is a positive operator on $F_1\oplus F_2$. Is the square root of $T$ given by
>   $$T^{1/2}=\begin{pmatrix}A^{1/2} & B^{1/2} \\
> C^{1/2} & D^{1/2}
> \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: No. $B$ and $C$ need not be positive operators.

Comment: If $T$ is positive then the operators $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ will be positive also.

Comment: Not true. The matrix with rows $(10,-1),(-1,10)$ is a positive definite, for example.

Comment: Thank you but I think that one can prove that the diagonal operators $A$ and $D$ are positive?

Comment: Yes, but since $B$ and $C$ may not have square roots there is no simple formula for $T^{1/2}$ in terms of its blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that $B$ and $C$ need not be positive (not even selfadjoint), what you ask is not true even if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are one-dimensional. Let $T\in M_2(\mathbb C)$ be 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then according to your formula you would expect to have $T^{1/2}=T$, but $T^2=2T$, so $T^{1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,T$. You also have that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-i\\i&1\end{bmatrix}\geq0,
$$
and it's not even clear how to apply your formula.

For a more dramatic example, let 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
Then its unique positive square root is 
$$
T^{1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt3}}{\sqrt{13}}\,\begin{bmatrix}
1+\sqrt3&1\\
1& 4+\sqrt3 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: It $T$ is diagonal, is the result holds? Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course.